# High system interrupt usage, how to troubleshoot?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-8.1

I have read through lots of article on the Internet and some thread in superuser but still can't figure it out what is the issue. Things I have tried:

- Disable fast startup
- Update driver (you can see no "?" or "!" in Device Manager)
- No high I/O access
- Fresh reinstall Windows 8.1 and Win10

This can be temporary solved by serval reboot. However, I can't figure it out what is the root cause, I have checked nothing special in Event Viewer, as "System interrupts" is not a "real" process. How can I troubleshoot it? 
[image]
[image]

Comment: Install the WPT (part of the Win10 SDK: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk), run WPRUI.exe, select "First Level", under  Resource select **CPU usage** and click on **start**. Now capture 1 minute of the Interrupt usage. After 1 minute click on **Save**. Zip the large ETL file, upload the zip (OneDrive, dropbox, google drive) and post the share link here.

Comment: Listen to magicandre and do what he says. :)

Comment: Yup, I read his message, but I can't reproduce this issue currently after serval reboots, it only occur in some time... I will update this question with the ETL file later :)

Comment: @magicandre1981 I have tried the recording, but when I stop and gonna save the file, it give me BSOD of KERNEL_SECURITY_CHECK FAILURE, I can only run it without BSOD when System Interrupts CPU utilization is normal.

Comment: share the dmp file from **C:\windows\Minidump**, so that I can try to debug it

Comment: @magicandre1981 Please check out this file http://www.filedropper.com/031616-8921-01

Comment: the dmp is corrupted, I can't really see anything from it. do some HW checks (memtest86+ for RAM errors and prime95 for CPU stability)